# Are implicit conversions for Scala numeric types special?

Tags: scala, numbers, implicit-conversion

I've defined an implicit class providing a method `foo` on all instances of `Double`. Strangely, this method can now also be called e.g. on `Float` instances, which is shown by the following example accepted by `scalac` 2.12.5 (use `-Xscript Foo`):

```
implicit class DoubleOps(value: Double) {
  def foo: Double = value
}

val x: Float = 1f
val y = x.foo
```

If I try to do the same with my own types, replacing `Float` and `Double` with `MyFloat` and `MyDouble` respectively, `foo` is not available on `MyFloat` instances.

```
trait MyDouble

object MyDouble {
  implicit class MyFloatAsMyDouble(value: MyFloat) extends MyDouble
}

trait MyFloat

implicit class MyDoubleOps(value: MyDouble) {
  def foo: MyDouble = value
}

val x: MyFloat = new MyFloat { }
val y = x.foo
```

```
$ scalac -Xscript Foo foo.scala
foo.scala:14: error: value foo is not a member of this.MyFloat
val y = x.foo
          ^
one error found
```

This is in line with my understand of how the compiler uses implicits to search for members not found on a type directly. But why does the first example still work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is a case of [numeric widening](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#value-conversions) achieved through [weak conformance](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#weak-conformance). (There is an active proposal to [drop this from the language](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposal-to-drop-weak-conformance-from-the-language/2819).)

Comment: Thanks! Those references are interesting. I can see how this applies to my observation. Dotty seems to have a [much more restricted](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/weak-conformance-spec.html) approach to numeric widening, probably resulting in less surprises.